# Density on 5inch 1080p Android mobile phones

Tags: android

New smartphones like the Sony Xperia Z have a insane high ppi like 443 ppi. Has anyone got his/her hands on such a device and can tell if this is still xhdpi or xxhdpi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sony Xperia Z is an xxhdpi device. In the Sony add-on SDK the AVD device definition of the Xperia Z has the xxhdpi pixel-density set.

Answer (score 0):

Sony also just confirmed xxhdpi on their developer blog: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/03/07/make-sure-your-app-does-not-exclude-xxhdpi-screens/